# want to add admob new ads id in existing app by update the app with new admob account

Tags: admob

I have an admob which is suspended for invalid activity. now i want to add a new admob account and add this new ads id to my existing app with an update. Is this possible? please give me some suggestion i am new in android developing.

Comment: Just replace your old Ad Unit ID with the new one.

Comment: @DanielStorm can that work? I had a similar issue and the support of admob told me to remove the ads completely, since my account and the applications them selves are banned now.

Comment: @ipinak thats correct. The ad serving is apparently disabled for the app (identified by its package name).

Answer (score 2):

What is the confusion?

1. **Create new ad units** for each existing ad unit in your app.
2. **Replace the ad units in your code** (from old admob account) with the new ad units (from your new account)
3. **Suggestion: (Optional)** Change the package name and take corrective actions to remove invalid activities which led to suspension of first account.
4. **Update your app**.

Make sure to **take corrective actions to remove the invalid activities** because of which your old admob account was suspended. Otherwise it will not be long before the new one gets suspended.

**Problem that you could face with just replacing the ad units in the same app:** The ad serving could have been disabled for your app's package name. If your app is relatively new with not a lot of users you may want to change the package name and relaunch it with compliance. **Hence, simple replacing may not work with same package name.**